# FreeDOS + RHIDE (DJGPP environment) = DOS Memory Corruption?

Tags: dos, virtualbox, corruption, memory-corruption, djgpp

I'm running a virtual machine (using Oracle VM VirtualBox) with FreeDOS installed.

After I enter the DJGPP IDE (called "RHIDE") and run an application once, I can no longer run anything, and when I exit the IDE, I get a message saying "dos mem corrupt" and "PANIC: MCB chain corrupted":

[image: RHIDE Memory Corruption Screenshot]

This happens for **every** program I run from RHIDE, and running the same programs "manually" from the FreeDOS command line yields no such problem.

It's quite bothersome to restart the VM after every debug session.

Any advice or ideas on what could be causing this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of DJGPP are you using? Basically it is best to use the last 2.04 beta available.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox is buggy. I'd suggest enabling VT-X if you can, but that won't fix everything either.

You may (or may not) have better luck with:

- BOCHS
- QEMU
- DOSBox
- DOSEMU
- VirtualPC
- OS/2 (or eCS)
- native FreeDOS
- WinXP

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal MS-DOS by Microsoft. Try with other cwsdpmi or djgpp version and send result.
I have a same problem with my assembler (FASM) apps.When I run it in FreeDOS sends me the same result. But when i run it on other platform it works.
This maybe problem with XMS/EMS extenders.